# Swift UISlider removing thumb tint not fully loaded issue

Tags: ios, swift, slider, uislider

i was working with UISlider and wanted to remove the Thumb tint so i made it with Clear color. but after removing thumb tint, it's not perfectly fully loaded.
how do i fix this? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use **user action** controls to increases or decreases slider value then
You can use UIProgressView instant of UISlider

[image]